# Making OpenFeign client + HTTPS + Loadbalancer work

Tags: spring-boot, openfeign

I've got a working OpenFeign client that talks http to a Spring Boot @RestController. I need to implement HTTPS + LoadBalancer including a ClientAuth cert on the OpenFeign side. I was able to implement HTTPS but when I throw in LoadBalancer on the client it throws UnknownHost with the name of the LoadBalancer service.

Is this configuration even possible? Any example projects anyone can recommend? I've searched around and never have found a suitable example.

Comment: Show your source code.

Comment: You need to tell us which registry center you are using, and the springboot and cloud versions.